# Providing custom ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I want to have some initialization code for my IIS-hosted service. I have read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/11/511514.aspx), it says (one of variants):

> By deriving from ServiceHost type, you can implement the protected
>   method ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime.

My question: Can I provide my own custom ServiceHost type to IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article suggests, you can provide a `ServiceHostFactory` to IIS that initializes your service host.

First, define the factory in the `.svc` file:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="SomeNamespace.MyServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Then create the factory and host classes:

```
class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}

class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public MyServiceHost()
    {
        // initialize, add endpoints, behaviors, etc.
    }
}
```

You can also override `InitializeRuntime` if you like. In the article they use it to log the virtual directory in which the service is running.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is via file-less activation in the Web.config file.  In your `<system.serviceModel>` section, add the following:

```
<serviceActivations>
  <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" 
       service="SomeNamespace.Service1" 
       factory="SomeNamespace.MyServiceHostFactory"/>
</serviceActivations>
```

This enables you to host a service in IIS without having a physical .svc file. This is a WCF 4.0+ feature, however.

Comment: It actually has to be under <serviceHostingEnvironment> See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816902(v=vs.110).aspx